# Class library creator?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am learning how to code by using standalone IDEs, but I need to create a .dll (class library) without Visual Studio or something that needs installing. Does anyone know how to use either a Hex Editor or a standalone app to create a .dll file that works?

Comment: `csc /target:library files.cs`...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e13syb43.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the command-line C# compiler?

```
csc /target:library File.cs
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Comment: Oh, I did find a standalone .dll editor: [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/#download) Thanks anyway.